# remove each listbox1 items after running the query?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a some items inside my listbox1 and want to use each items to run a query, once the query is runned, I want to delete that item inside listbox and use next item to run the query. For example If item1 is used than delete item1 and use next item inside listbox to run the query.Do this for all the items till no items left inside the listbox1.

```
foreach (string myItems in listBox1.Items)
{
    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(select REGEXP_REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('" + myItems + "'), conn1))
    {
        string expectedresult = "y";
        string dataresult = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (expectedresult == dataresult)
        {
            //do something and remove the item that has been used to run the query.                                   
        }
        else
        {

        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly in your foreach loop. It will give you exception '**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute**' if you try to do this inside your foreach loop. Rather after executing your entire query you can delete them all.

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Incase you want to keep a track of items that have been executed you can create a

```
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>();
ids.Add(yourIdToAdd);
```

and add your executed ids in that.

Comment: How can I use HashSet<T>?

Comment: @EhsanUllah, why would you use `Items.Clear()` and a `HashSet` together? One forces all items to go away, the other is just Brian's answer with a HashSet instead of a List.

Comment: @gunr2171 Have you read the answer fully? I have clearly said 'Incase you want to keep a track of items that have been executed you can create a Hashset'. Both are different things and are totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to other's opinions, you **can** use a foreach loop to delete items. The key is you have to make a `copy` of the list before you try to iterate through it.

Add `.ToList()` to the end. If `Items` is a `Collection`, then you need to typecast it into the proper type with `.OfType<string>().ToList()`.

```
foreach (string myItems in listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToList())
{
    ....
}
```

Now you are free to delete the items in `listBox.Items` without changing the list your are iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the removal inline in a foreach since you would be modifying the list as you are trying to iterate over it. I would keep track of the indexes of the ones you want to remove and then do it in a separate call. Something like:

```
List<int> removeIndexes = new List<int>();
int i = 0;
foreach (string myItems in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(select REGEXP_REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('" + myItems + "'), conn1))
                    {
                        string expectedresult = "y";
                        string dataresult = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                        if (expectedresult == dataresult)
                        {
                          //do something and remove the item that has been used to run the query.                    
                          removeIndexes.add(i);               
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        } 
                     }
                     i++;
                 }

foreach (int index in removeIndexes)
{
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot remove items from a list in a foreach loop, it throws an exception when changing the collection.
You should use a normal for loop . Your code should look something like:

```
  for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count -1; i>=0; i--)
      {
            string myItems = listBox1.Items[i];
            using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(select REGEXP_REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('" + myItems + "'), conn1))
                        {
                            string expectedresult = "y";
                            string dataresult = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                            if (expectedresult == dataresult)
                            {
                               listBox1.RemoveAt(i);
                           }
                            else
                            {

                            } 
                         }
                     }
```

Comment: You are doing `listBox1.Items[i]`, but you are `RemoveAt(0)`. Don't you mean `RemoveAt(i)`?